# slow mysql query with inner join 0846 sec

Tags: mysql, inner-join, performance

I have another problem when i used query with INNER JOIN

this query

```
SELECT *
FROM `engine4_product_file` INNER JOIN
     `engine4_file`
     ON engine4_product_file.fid = engine4_file.id
WHERE engine4_product_file.pid IN (3347,3346,3345,3343,3342,3337) and
      engine4_file.active = 1 AND
      engine4_file.ext IN ('jpg','gif','png','jpeg')
```

and this create table engine4_product_file

```
 CREATE TABLE `engine4_product_file` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `engine4_product_file` (`fid`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6549 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and this create table engine4_file

```
CREATE TABLE `engine4_file` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `folder` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48801 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this explain

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  engine4_product_file    range   engine4_product_file,pid    pid     4   NULL    30  Using where
1   SIMPLE  engine4_file    eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   akafine_social2.engine4_product_file.fid    1   Using where
```

Comment: Both your tables have the same name?Which is which?Also what`s the problem,I only see 30 rows,is that really slow?

Comment: I think there's a cut'n'paste error since you added the same table twice.

Comment: I just want to get the best way to add Indexes for this tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your WHERE conditions

```
  WHERE  engine4_file.active = 1 AND
         engine4_file.ext IN ('jpg','gif','png','jpeg') AND
  engine4_product_file.pid IN (3347,3346,3345,3343,3342,3337)
```

Add an index

```
 ALTER TABLE engine4_file ADD KEY (active,ext)
```